# How can I ensure an array or list data type within Python3 using the structures package

Tags: python, data-structures, python-3.6

I am playing around with the structures 2.0.2 package to create data structures in Python3.  If I write the following code it will ensure that the variable `i` is an Integer when defined at a later time.

```
from structures import *
class S(Structure):
    i = Integer

Test = S()
Test.i = 4
print (Test.i)
Test.i = 4.18
print (Test.i)
Test.i = 'A string'
print (Test.i)
```

This will yield 4 for the first two print statements and an error for the third because I tried to change the data type to something that could not be rounded to the correct data type.

However, lets say I want the variable `i` to be a list or a bumpy array populated only with integers.  I try the following;

```
Test.i = [45,37.8,14.3]
```

and I get an error telling me that I cannot turn the variable `i` into a list.  If I try the following;

```
from structures import *
class S(Structure):
    i = [Integer]

Test.i = [45,37.8,14.3]
```

The code will execute and create a list, but the values are not constrained to an integer.  How can I get the structures package to constrain the data types within lists and bumpy arrays to a static type?

Comment: The library you're using was last updated 3 years back and as far as I can tell it doesn't support your requirement.  Either move on to a similar library that is actively developed and supports similar functionality or use static analyzers like [Mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/) for this. For Mypy you could define it as `List[int]`, where `List` is from [`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using structures. You will have to build your own [custom type](http://zzzsochi.github.io/structures/types.html#building-custom-types). The list type just do a list() cast before assigning the value, so if you want beside do a list cast do an int cast to each item of the list, you will have to implement it ;)